# How to search for Specific Rows in R and return that row's information back

Tags: r, subset

I am working with RNA seq data with Gene names as my first column and cluster gene expression data as the following columns. There are a lot of genes however I am only interested in about 200 of them. Is there a way to just target those specific genes and then create a data matrix with them. I can retrieve information from columns

```
Mydata.1 <- x[c("Gene Name", "Cluster_1")]
```

But not rows for example this fails

```
Mydata.1 <- x[c("Malat1", "Cd74")]
```

does anyone know how I would be able to do that? 
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer uses a logical vector for subsetting your dataframe rows. For more on this take a look at: http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Subsetting.html#data-types.

```r
# Mockup data
x <- data.frame(
  `Gene Name` = c("HPRT1", "ABC", "Malat1", "Cd74"),
  Cluster_1 = 1:4,
  Cluster_2 = 5:8,
  check.names = FALSE
)

# Defining gene names of interest to look for
target_genes <- c("Malat1", "Cd74")

# Getting a logical vector that implicitly codes for row positions
# Note: we need to wrap Gene Name in backticks (``) because of the space character in "Gene Name"
row_matches <- x$`Gene Name` %in% target_genes

# Subsetting the gene expression  matrix (actually a dataframe object)
# mydata2: dataframe whose rows are for target genes only
# Note: the empty placeholder after the comma in the subsetting below indicates all columns
mydata2 <- x[row_matches, ]

mydata2
#>   Gene Name Cluster_1 Cluster_2
#> 3    Malat1         3         7
#> 4      Cd74         4         8
```

Alternatively we can also use the function `subset` for more concise code:

```r
# Mockup data
x <- data.frame(
  `Gene Name` = c("HPRT1", "ABC", "Malat1", "Cd74"),
  Cluster_1 = 1:4,
  Cluster_2 = 5:8,
  check.names = FALSE
)

# Defining gene names of interest to look for
target_genes <- c("Malat1", "Cd74")

# As an alternative use the function subset
mydata2 <- subset(x, `Gene Name` %in% target_genes)

mydata2
#>   Gene Name Cluster_1 Cluster_2
#> 3    Malat1         3         7
#> 4      Cd74         4         8
```

Comment: Thanks, this helped! especially the comments!

Comment: @Jimjilbang: You're welcome. Feel free to mark it as the correct answer if you're happy with it. :)

Comment: Didn't know that was an option, new to this. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To find data you want, you can use this code :

newdata <- mydata[ which(mydata$gene=='THE_GENE_U_LOOK_FOR', ]